# RegEx in VSCode: capture every character/letter - not just ASCII

Tags: regex, xml, visual-studio-code

I am working with historical text and I want to reformat it with RegEx. Problem is: There are lots of special characters (that is: letters) in the text that are not matched by RegEx character classes like [a-z] / [A-Z] or \w .
For example I want to match the dot (and only the dot) in the following line:

```
<tag1>Quomodo restituendus locus Demosth. Olÿnth</tag1>
```

Without the ÿ I could easily work with the mentioned character classes, like:

```
(?<=(<tag1>(\w|\s)*))\.(?=((\w|\s)*</tag1>))
```

But it does not work with special characters that are not covered by ASCII. I tried lots of things but I can't make it work so the RegEx really only captures the dot in this very line. If I use more general Expressions like (.)* (instead of (\w|\s)* ) I get many more of the dots in the document (for example dots that are not between an opening and a closing tag but in between two such tagsets), which is not what I want. Any ideas for an expression that covers like all unicode letters?

Comment: Are you saying that this `\.` does not match a dot ?

Comment: Note that a xml regex would not be appropriate. And note that it doesn't matter what is in between and you don't need positive assertions to insure a dot is between an open and closing tag. It would take half this page for me to explain this in detail. This is Unicode irrelevant !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match any text between `<` and `>` with `[^<>]*`:

```js
(?<=(<tag1>[^<>]*))\.(?=([^<>]*</tag1>))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vcAKkq/1). Not sure you need all those capturing groups, you might get what you need without them:

```js
(?<=<tag1>[^<>]*)\.(?=[^<>]*</tag1>)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vcAKkq/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=<tag1>[^<>]*)` - a location immediately preceded with `<tag1` and then any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=[^<>]*</tag1>)` - a location immediately preceded with any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then `</tag1>`.

Answer (score 0):

use a negated character class that exculdes the dot and the opening angle bracket:

```
(?<=<tag1>[^.<]*(?:<(?!/tag1>)[^.<]*)*)\.
```

with this kind of pattern it isn't even needed to check the closing tag. But if you absolutely want to check it, ends the pattern with:

```
(?=[^<]*(?:<(?!/tag1>)[^<]*)*</tag1>)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works indeed perfect under one condition: That there is only one dot between the tags. I know, I did not specify this but in my case there can be several dots (in fact they are used to mark abbreviations and for example in names it can look like this: <tag1>J. R. Ewing</tag1>)